# iOS-Charts Line Graph with shadow under the line and fill gradient

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm using ios-charts framework to implement a line graph like the one displayed below.

[Line Graph With Background Gradient and Shadow under the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRni.png)

The documentation cannot be very specific on everything we want to create so maybe someone has an idea on how to implement this.

So what i need to do is the following:

Add a background gradient, which currently is not presented on the image because of the limit line. 
Add a shadow below the line that shows the values.

Over the limit line, the fill color begins to get red and as it goes to higher values, it gets more and more red.
As you can see, the shadow has an angle (-45 degrees). It's not relevant at this point, i just want to add the shadow over the line without any angle.

I've seen some examples that say that they add shadow under the line but they are not working and they are not allowing to add a fill color.

Thank you in advance :)